# number of ways to obtain a given permutation from k swaps

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, cayley-graphs

Let $\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_b \in S_n$ be all the 2-cycles ("swaps") in $S_n$. (So, $b = \binom{n}{2}$.) Given some $\pi \in S_n$, is there a known formula for how many ways to obtain $\pi$ as a product of $k$ swaps? (This can of course be zero when $k$ is too small.) It is easy to see that the answer only depends on the conjugacy class of $\pi$. Thus, I'm wondering whether there is some nice formula in terms of $k$, $n$, and the sizes of the cycles in the cycle-decomposition of $\pi$.

Comment: You should request moving this question to math overflow.

Comment: This is a good suggestion which I have now carried out. The math overflow question is here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/146890/how-many-ways-can-a-given-permutation-be-obtained-as-a-product-of-k-2-cycles